# Multiple graphical modes switching during startup

Tags: display, lxde, u-boot, angstrom, bootsplash

I have a small ARM board with Linux (Angström, kernel 4.1) and have connected it to a HDMI display. It works at the moment. I would like to show a splashscreen during the whole startup but it seems to be impossible. I use an `init.d` script with the `fbi` utility to display a picture but it's shown only for 3-4 seconds in the middle of startup. I have analyzed bootup sequence and found that the graphical mode was switched many times during the startup.

I have an HDMI display with a 1024x600 resolution. The bootup sequence is attached. You can see the following switches:

- 0.21 s - 720x576
- 0.37, 1.37 s - 640x480
- 1.42 s - 640x480 1.87 s - 640x480
- 2.22 s - 1024x600 (the right one! The splashscreen is probably displayed after that action)
- 9 - 14s - 6 (!) times the same resolution 1024x600, what should it mean?

I start the kernel from Uboot with the following command:

```
mxc_hdmi.only_cea=0 video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1024x600M@60,if=RGB24
```

And the picture was shown just for ca. 3-4 seconds after 2 seconds, so there is something wrong between the 7th second and the 9th second, no switching was here but also no picture on the screen.

How should I fix it and let the picture in the screen for the full duration of the startup routine? Why does the system switch the resolutions so many times during startup?  The GUI of the system is LXDE.

[Bootup log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7nSIHJmo4hxM1pUeXFUMVJWU1E)